# Resetting a variable in a recursive Lua function

Tags: recursion, lua, scope

I'm writing a very simple program in Lua to learn more about genetic programming. Below is a mutate function to go to a numbered node (`nodeNum`) in the tree (`pop`) and either : swap add with sub (or vice-versa) or replace the node with a random number 1-100.

```
local count = 0
function mutate(pop, nodeNum)
    for k,v in ipairs(pop) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            mutate(v, nodeNum)
        else
            count = count + 1
        end

        if count == nodeNum and k == 1 then -- correct node
            if type(v) == "function" then
                if v == add then
                    pop[k] = sub
                else
                    pop[k] = add
                end
            else
                pop[k] = math.random(100)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My problem is with `count`. Calling this function is awkward, since `count` has to be reset each time :

```
-- mutate the first 3 elements in program tree t 
mutate(t,1)
count = 0
mutate(t, 2)
count = 0
mutate(t, 3)
```

I've tried variations using `do ... end` like :

```
do
    local count
    function mutate(pop, nodeNum)
    if not count then
        count = 0
    ...
end
```

I've also tried giving mutate an extra argument `mutate(pop, nodeNum, count)` and calling it with `mutate(t, 1, 0)` but I can't get either method to work correctly.

I may be missing something really obvious, can anyone see a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mutate(pop, nodeNum, count)
    count = count or 0

    for k,v in ipairs(pop) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            mutate(v, nodeNum, count)
        else
            count = count + 1
        end

        if count == nodeNum and k == 1 then -- correct node
            if type(v) == "function" then
                if v == add then
                    pop[k] = sub
                else
                    pop[k] = add
                end
            else
                pop[k] = math.random(100)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple. It's even in _Programming in Lua_!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use Lua, but, wouldn't the easiest way would probably be to make another function that calls this one, which sets count to zero after the current method returns? Ex:

```
function mutateExample(pop, nodeNum)
    mutate(pop, nodeNum)
    count = 0;
end
```

That way, mutate can call itself recursively all it wants and then count will be reset once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

`count` needs to be a local variable *within* the function, not outside of it. It's a stack variable, so put it in the function's stack:

```
function mutate(pop, nodeNum)
    local count = 0

    for k,v in ipairs(pop) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            mutate(v, nodeNum)
        else
            count = count + 1
        end

        if count == nodeNum and k == 1 then -- correct node
            if type(v) == "function" then
                if v == add then
                    pop[k] = sub
                else
                    pop[k] = add
                end
            else
                pop[k] = math.random(100)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You only use external `local` variables if you want multiple function invocations to *share* the variable.

Comment: This solution resets `count` each time the function is recursively called, but what I need is a static variable that is reset _only_ when the function has finished it's recursion.